# Building blocks for unimodular matrices

Tags: integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization

I read Chapter 19.4 of Schrijver(1986) and get to know that every totally unimodular matrix can be produced by taking operations on network matrices and two certain matrices. I find that some paper says that there are similar building blocks for unimodular matrices. Could you tell me what the building blocks for unimodular matrices are? Why does the decomposition of totally unimodular matrices apply to the decomposition of unimodular matrices?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what the paper is which says that there are similar building blocks for unimodular matrices,

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Danilov and Grishukhin(1999)"Maximal Unimodular Systems of Vectors". The last paragraph on page 2 says that "a study of unimodular systems is a study of totally unimodular matrices in an invariant way" and "Once more, the invariant way is a study of regular
(= unimodular) matroids". It seems that the decompositions of these three objects all come from Seymour(1980).